# How do access the attributes of a method's Parameters

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

How do you determine if a parameter has a custom attribute attached to it?

I thought this test case would pass:

```
    [TestCase("")]
    public void TestParameterAttribute([NotRequired]string theString)
    {
        var result = false;

        foreach (var attribute in theString.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(true))
        {
            if (attribute.GetType() == (typeof(NotRequiredAttribute)))
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }

        Assert.That(result, Is.True);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires a little bit more work.

```
[TestCase("")]
public void TestParameterAttribute([NotRequired]string theString)
{
    var method = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
    var parameter = method.GetParameters()[0];
    var result = false;

    foreach (var attribute in parameter.GetCustomAttributes(true))
    {
        if (attribute.GetType() == (typeof(NotRequiredAttribute)))
        {
            result = true;
        }
    }

    Assert.That(result, Is.True);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`theString.GetType()` gets a reference to the `Type` representing a `string`. Calling `GetCustomAttributes` on it will look in the `string` class for those attributes.

What you want to do.. is get the attributes for the parameters in the current method. Maybe something like this:

```
var result = false;

foreach (var parameter in MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters())
{
    if (parameter.GetCustomAttributes().Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof (NotRequiredAttribute)))
        result = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use Generic version of [`GetCustomAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
parameter.GetCustomAttribute<NotRequiredAttribute>() != null
```